# JSP- getting array data into jsp from java

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have to display data fetched from DB to JSP. I am using spring MVC. I have stored data in List in java. Now i need to access this list in JSP and display it in tabular form.

Data needs to represented in tabular form from List and VO, column names and row names  coming from List and corresponding values for row/column from object.
e.g

```
         Column1  Column2  Column3   Column4
Row1       A         B         C       D
Row2       E         F         G       H
```

How can i pass this List and Object in jsp from java.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Process it on servlet and store it in 2D array of `String` or `List<List<String>>`
- Set it as attribute to request, forward request to jsp.
- on jsp use JSTL to represent data. using `<c:forEach>`

Answer (score 0):

You can add your data in session and access it in `table.jsp`.

Once you get data on JSP you can easily render as you want using html + jsp combination.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is no need to store data in session unless it requires to persist for more than one request

Answer (score 0):

```
List<List<?>> data = new ArrayList<List<?>>();
int col = -1;
List<?> row;
while(rs.next())
{
  if (col != rs.getInt(1))
  {
    col = rs.getInt(1);
    row = new ArrayList<?>();
    data.add(row);
  }
  row.add(rs.getObject(3));
}
getRequest().setAttribute(data);
```

Comment: Hi, i have defined a Arraylist of ArrayList of String in Java to store data row wise. eg. [[R, W, W, R], [W, R, R, W], [W, W, W, R]]. It is stored in java as ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> at = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();     Now i want to get this value in jsp, so i have added to Model(Spring). But i dont know how to fetch ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> in jsp. for ArrayList<String> as = new ArrayList<String>(); i have used ${at} in jsp. it there a way to access arraylist of arraylist in jsp

Comment: I did the same ${at}, but instead of getting [R,W,W,R], i am getting  [[R, W, W, R], [W, R, R, W], [W, W, W, R]]. I want to access array within the array